# How to resize image in html content to fit in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I've read various solutions to resize the image inside html string to fit the width of screen in `UITextView` but it's not working. Following is my code. It still goes out of bound in width. How to fix this?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.contentTextView.attributedText = self.content?.htmlAttributed(textView: self.contentTextView, family: "SFProText-Regular", size: 14.0, color: .myWhite)
}

extension String {

    func htmlAttributed(textView: UITextView, family: String?, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let htmlCSSString = "<head><style type=\"text/css\">" +
                "html *" +
                "{" +
                "font-size: \(size)px !important;" +
                "color: #\(color.hexString!) !important;" +
                "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica !important;" +
                "line-height:1.5;" +
                "img{ max-height: 100%; max-width: \(textView.frame.size.width) !important; width: auto; height: auto;}" +
                "}</style></head>" +
            "<body> \(self) <body>"

            guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return nil
            }

            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

**Following is the formatted string from debug console**

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">html *{font-size: 14.0px !important;color: #FFFFFF !important;font-family: SFProText-Regular, Helvetica !important;line-height:1.5;img{ max-height: 100%; max-width: 382.0 !important; width: auto; height: auto;}}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name=viewport>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-h4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <p>Text <strong><a href="domain.com">Link</a></strong> More text</p>
    <p>Text....</p>
    <div class="aligncenter">
        <figure class="image">
            <a href="domain.com/image.jpg"><img alt="Alt text" height="auto" class="img-responsive" src="domain.com/image.jpg" /> </a>
            <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">h1{font-size: 20px;}h2{font-size: 18px;}h3{font-size: 16px;}</style>
    <body>
```

Comment: try to add `<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\" />` before `<html>` tag

Comment: Didn't help same result